# Why can we prove things via the contrapositive, contradiction, etc.?

Tags: logic, meta-math

I don't understand why we can use things as the contrapositive, reductio, etc. when we look to prove some statement.

If we look at this from something like axiomatic propositional logic we can say that 
$$
(p\implies q)\implies(\neg q \implies\neg p)
$$
and
$$
(\neg q \implies \neg p) \implies(p\implies q)
$$

Are theorems, but only if we have the necessary axioms/rules of inference, what happens if we don't?

If we interpret this formulas semantically, on the other hand, its obvious that both formulas are tautologies. And  similar argument goes for proofs by contradiction.

So, from this, I gather that when we normally look to prove an implication in mathematics, we follow the rules that semantic propositional logic dictate, why do we accept this?

Somehow related: [What the Tortoise said to Achilles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles)

Comment: There are logic systems, like intuitionistic logic, that don't allow reductio and contrapositive.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 That's what I was aiming at: If there are logic systems where things like that are not allowed, why do we take one which accepts them as our framework?

Comment: Primarily because the ancient Greeks accepted excluded middle, and then everyone learnt their logic from Euclid, so it's been the norm for almost as long as mathematics itself has been studied.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Primarily because most people accept the required axioms and rules of inference as self-evident. A few don’t; most of us are not persuaded by their arguments.

Answer (score 2):

For me, a convincing argument is already included in your question:

> If we interpret this formulas semantically, on the other hand, its obvious that both formulas are tautologies. And similar argument goes for proofs by contradiction.
>   So, from this, I gather that when we normally look to prove an implication in mathematics, we follow the rules that semantic propositional logic dictate, why do we accept this?

My interest in logic is (most of the time) *semantics driven*: I have some notion of "structure" or "truth assignment" I'm already interested in, and then I try to understand what the corresponding logic is. Individual axioms/inference rules are justified one by one, and the appropriate completeness theorem tells me when I'm "done".

Of course, the dual of this attitude is equally true of me: that, to the extent that (say) I'm interested in sheaves of first-order structures, then I'm using intuitionistic logic. And this attitude is irrelevant if I'm interested in some formal system for its own sake (e.g. linear logic looks pretty cool, regardless of its semantics). But if you ask my what logic is my "default," for me that's the same as asking what *semantics* is my "default".

---

There is a certain circularity here - how do I understand a semantic framework without a logic underpinning my thoughts, already? - but this is part of the point of the Tortoise and Achilles parable: we have to start somewhere.